# Writing pseudo code for camel cap into array

Tags: python, arrays, pseudocode

a friend asked me the other day to help him write pseudo code that would separate each word of the following string "HelloWorld" and store it in an array [x] with unused array elements with an empty string.

I actually didn't know where to start, I programmed it instead in Python however used some functions like in [A-Z] [a-z] to detect upper and lower cases so it knows when to split the strings but how do you even go about writing that in pseudo code since it doesn't have any official documentation?

Comment: Just for the record: it is always helpful if the OP gives some feedback if the answers help him; or if something is missing ...

Comment: Hello, all these responses seem perfect and I've passed this back to my friend, I will see if he has any questions, I have up voted the responses

Comment: I am glad you got the help you were looking for. But: you did not upvote any of the answers! these 2 upvotes for the other answers were coming from me. You first have to accept an answer, to reach 15 rep before you are even able to upvote!

Comment: I did up vote however it said they won't count publicly because my rep is less than 15 but it still counted for something else, so please don't tell me I didn't do something when I did. I have now ticked one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale behind pseudo code is to describe an algorithm. Normally you leave the gory details for a language implementation. But the fact is that you have to decide what level you write and what level you leave.

Here I would write:

```
declare an array of 10 strings arr initialized to empty strings
set arr_index to 0
initialize index to first position in string
loop
    find first uppercase letter after index
    if none find: exit loop
    if found at new_index
        copy characters from index (inclusive) to new_index (exclusive) to a new string
        store that string in arr[arr_index]
        increment arr_index
        set index = new_index
end loop
arr_index is the number of words found
```

Here I have left the research of an uppercase letter and the copy of a substring to a new string for the implementer, but IMHO the description is enough to write this immediately in C, C++ Python or Java (the languages I know)

Answer (score 1):

It's pseudo code.

You *define* what it "works".

Like: it could be enough to simply state:

> there is some

```
fun isUpperCase(char c)
```

> that returns true/false based on the case-ness of `c`.

And then your algorithm makes use of that function for example.

The **idea** of pseudo code is to describe the **essential** parts of an algorithm. How such a function really works isn't of interest; just say "we have such a function"; and then start using it.

In other words: you worry how to express a regex/splitting in pseudo-code terms. Don't - that is already an (less important) implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example pseudocode:

```
create empty array
set offset = 0
for each character in "HelloWorldThisIsCamelCase":
  if character is uppercase:
    increment offset
  append character to array element at offset
```